# Return Count if linked table does not contain specific value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am linking two tables in Microsoft SQL Server. The one table contains documents and the other contains the event status, which I need to specify a condition.

On the documents table, I am looking at the document code which is linked to the event, for example `371268-INV-1` and `371268-INV-1-APPROVED`. There should be 2 documents per event.

I need to return values/ counts where the status from the Events table is approved but where there is no document code containing Approved.

I started out using:

```
select * from Documents
join EVENTS on event_code = left (document_code, 6) 
where document_code like '371268%' and Event_Status = 'Approved'
```

Comment: is `371268-INV-1-APPROVED` the `Event_Status` value?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

This will get all events that are approved that do not have 2 records in the documents table. I think this will get you the results you are looking for.

```
select * 
from events
where event_status = 'approved'
   and event_code not in(select left (document_code, 6) 
                         from documents 
                         group by left (document_code, 6) 
                         having count <>2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, this is what you need

```
select * from Documents
join EVENTS on event_code = left (document_code, 6) 
WHERE 
EVENTS.Event_Status = 'Approved' AND Documents.document_code NOT LIKE '%APPROVED';
```